# What are my options between SQL Server 2008 to 2016 regarding column-level encryption and client data access (ado.net or entity)

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, ado.net, ssrs-2008, oledb

So I've been reading about SQL Server 2016 and Always Encrypted, but upgrading might not be an option in the short term. However, it's probably the best option given the number of different apps, reports etc accessing the given database using either entity framework, ado.net and/or oledb. I like the idea of simply adding the extra connection string option and having the encryption happen both at rest and in motion.

What are the options for SQL Server versions prior to 2016 and how much extra work is it regarding client apps connecting via entity framework, ado.net, oledb (ssrs, ssis etc) and odbc dsn connections.

After doing a bit of research, the Always Encrypted option is simply the best that I can see so far.

**Question:**
Is it correct to say that using something on a version of SQL prior to 2016 will require direct modification of the client data access code to handle the encrypt/decrypt aspects?

While that might have been an option when these client apps were being written, its not really a good option now.

Comment: Careful. If you have many different apps and they're accessing the database in many different ways, Always Encrypted is not always a hassle-free, drop-in solution, because a lot of query patterns become impossible. Specifically, because the database has no access to the unencrypted values anymore, operations on strings are very limited (`WHERE Column = @value` will work, `WHERE Column LIKE @pattern` will not). While the encryption itself is transparent, the consequences are not, so first look into how the columns you want to encrypt are used.

Comment: Ahh, good point.  I had been reading about the impact on existing queries.  However, I did not notice the example of using LIKE, which is most likely present in many queries these apps use.  Hmm, need to do more research.